# `useState`, only update component when values in object change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

## Problem

`useState` always triggers an update even when the data's values haven't changed.

Here's a working demo of the problem: [demo](https://codepen.io/agconti/pen/RwNJLep?editors=0011)

### Background

I'm using the `useState` hook to update an object and I'm trying to get it to only update when the values in that object change. Because React uses the [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description) comparison algorithm to determine when it should update; objects with equivalent values still cause the component to re-render because they're different objects.

Ex. This component will always re-render even though the value of the payload stays as `{ foo: 'bar' }`

```js
const UseStateWithNewObject = () => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState({});
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setInterval(() => {
        setPayload({ foo: 'bar' });
      }, 500);
    },
    [setPayload]
  );

  renderCountNewObject += 1;
  return <h3>A new object, even with the same values, will always cause a render: {renderCountNewObject}</h3>;
};
```

## Question

Is there away that I can implement something like `shouldComponentUpdate` with hooks to tell react to only re-render my component when the data changes?

Comment: Can you add the logic that you would use in `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `useEffect` callback and call `setPayload` only if the new value is not the same as `payload` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we would need to see a better real life example of what you are tying to do, but from what you have shared I think the logic would need to move upstream to a point before the state gets set.

For example, you could manually compare the incoming values in a `useEffect` before you update state, because this is basically what you are asking if React can do for you.

There is a library `use-deep-compare-effect` https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect that may be of use to you in this case, taking care of a lot of the manual effort involved, but even then, this solution assumes the developer is going to manually decide (based on incoming props, etc) if the state should be updated.

So for example:

```
const obj = {foo: 'bar'}
const [state, setState] = useState(obj)

useEffect(() => {
   // manually deep compare here before updating state
   if(obj.foo === state.foo) return
   setState(obj)
},[obj])
```

EDIT:  Example using `useRef` if you don't use the value directly and don't need the component to update based on it:

```
const obj = {foo: 'bar'}
const [state, setState] = useState(obj)

const { current: payload } = useRef(obj)

useEffect(() => {
    // always update the ref with the current value - won't affect renders
    payload = obj

    // Now manually deep compare here and only update the state if 
    //needed/you want a re render
    if(obj.foo === state.foo) return
    setState(obj)
},[obj])
```

Comment: It's a neat idea to check equality in the effect before setting the state! For me, this breaks separation of concerns though. `useEffect` should only be worried about keeping the state updated. Whereas the component should determine how and when it should be rendered. For example, if I turned this logic into a custom hook, it might be advantageous for another component to always update and another to only update when there's a change

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have a setInterval doing setState({whatever}) you are always setting the state to a new object. Which absolutely should trigger a rerender. Putting logic first, and only returning a new object if data has changed is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @CalIrvine I disagree. What I'm trying to do is the reason why [`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) exists in React. `payload` *isn't used* as a determining factor for output so it shouldnt cause a re-render. I could implement this with a class component or through tools like `recompose` and it would work nicely. There's no reason to mix concerns here.

Comment: @agconti The thing with `useEffect` though is it is meant to replace component lifecycle events, so anything you could do with those lifecycle events in a class based approach can be done with `useEffect`.  I see where you are coming from with seperation of concerns, but having multiple `useEffects` could possibly fix that.  Nothing says you have to have all of your logic in one effect.

Comment: @CalIrvine a better way of doing what you've suggested is already outlined in my demo. I can get `Object.is` to update only on changed values by treating the object as a string with `JSON.stringify`. This works but for previously mentioned reasons, i'd like to find another way.

Comment: @TravisJames how do you think I could split up this example into more `useEffects` to get it to update only based on value? I guess I could separate my object into many more `useStates` and that should work. `payload` isn't used in rendering my component so its a shame to do so much work to control the render cycle.

Comment: Also for more context, in my actual application, I get this payload from an event listener that dispatches different types of events. The payload has different for each event @TravisJames

Comment: @agconti if payload isn't used in rendering and you don't want the component to re render when the value changes could you use a `useRef`?  That would make things quite a bit easier.  If so I can update my answer with an example of how I would use that approach?

Comment: @agconti I updated my answer with an example of using a ref.  A useRef is just a mutable object with a current property that stays consistent throughout renders, it doesn't actually have to be a reference to anything.  It has come in handy for me many times.  I'm not sure if it will solve your problem eloquently or not though.

Comment: @TravisJames I checked this out myself and it works great. The hooks FAQ even [kinda suggest](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) doing this. It takes some getting used to for me because I still think of ref's as references to dom nodes . Thanks for your help!

Comment: @agconti No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 19):

If I understand well, you are trying to only call `setState` whenever the new value for the state has changed, thus preventing unnecessary rerenders when it has NOT changed.

If that is the case you can take advantage of the callback form of [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
setState(prevState => {
  // here check for equality and return prevState if the same

  // If the same
  return prevState; // -> NO RERENDER !

  // If different
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues}; // Rerender
});
```

Here is a custom hook (in TypeScript) that does that for you automatically. It uses `isEqual` from lodash. But feel free to replace it with whatever equality function you see fit.

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useMemoizedState = <T>(initialValue: T): [T, (val: T) => void] => {
  const [state, _setState] = useState<T>(initialValue);

  const setState = (newState: T) => {
    _setState((prev) => {
      if (!isEqual(newState, prev)) {
        return newState;
      } else {
        return prev;
      }
    });
  };

  return [state, setState];
};

export default useMemoizedState;
```

Usage:

```
const [value, setValue] = useMemoizedState({ [...] });
```

Comment: oh my god this is a criminally underrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there away that I can implement something like shouldComponentUpdate with hooks to tell react to only re-render my component when the data changes?

Commonly, for state change you compare with previous value before rendering with functional `useState` or a reference using `useRef`:

```
// functional useState
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const curr = { foo: 'bar' };
    setPayload(prev => (isEqual(prev, curr) ? prev : curr));
  }, 500);
}, [setPayload]);
```

```
// with ref
const prev = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const curr = { foo: 'bar' };
    if (!isEqual(prev.current, curr)) {
      setPayload(curr);
    }
  }, 500);
}, [setPayload]);

useEffect(() => {
  prev.current = payload;
}, [payload]);
```

---

For completeness, "re-render my component when the data changes?" may be referred to props too, so in this case, you should use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

[image: Edit affectionate-hellman-ujtbv]

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution to this that does not involve adding logic to your effects, is to split your components into:

- uncontrolled container with state that renders...
- dumb controlled stateless component that has been memoized with `React.memo`

Your dumb component can be pure (as if it had `shouldComponentUpdate` implemented and your smart state handling component can be "dumb" and not worry about updating state to the same value.

Example:

### Before

```
export default function Foo() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ foo: "1" })
  const handler = useCallback(newValue => setState({ foo: newValue }))

  return (
    <div>
      <SomeWidget onEvent={handler} />
      Value: {{ state.foo }}
    </div>
  )
```

### After

```
const FooChild = React.memo(({foo, handler}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeWidget onEvent={handler} />
      Value: {{ state.foo }}
    </div>
  )
})

export default function Foo() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ foo: "1" })
  const handler = useCallback(newValue => setState({ foo: newValue }))

  return <FooChild handler={handler} foo={state.foo} />
}
```

This gives you the separation of logic you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

You can use memoized components, they will re-render only on prop changes.

```
const comparatorFunc = (prev, next) => {
  return prev.foo === next.foo
}

const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(({payload}) => {
    return (<div>{JSON.stringify(payload)}</div>)
}, comparatorFunc);
```

Comment: There's no props here, just state. From the docs "React.memo doesn’t compare state because there is no single state object to compare. But you can make children pure too, or even optimize individual children with useMemo." Here's an demo of it not working: https://codepen.io/agconti/pen/oNgypaV?editors=0011

Comment: @agconti First of all, you have to learn how to use React.memo, then you have to clarify for yourself when ACTUALLY render happens in react

Comment: There's no props here, that's correct, and the only reason UseStateWithNewObject component ACTUALLY re-renders is beacuse renderCountNewObject is present inside of `h3`. If you remove it though, your console log will be called anyways, but it doesnt mean that DOM node is being rendered each time. And I never stated that you have to wrap UseStateWithNewObject in React.memo. You have to optimize child components